# The RESTFul way for counting rows in a table, in a database

Tags: node.js, rest, express, nestjs

I have the following route (`api/v1/users`) which returns an array of JSON objects holding users, each object represents a row in the table:

```json
# GET /api/v1/users
# response body | status code 200
{
  message: "success"  
  data: [
   { id: 1, name: "A" },
   { id: 2, name: "B" },
   { id: 3, name: "C" },
  ]
}
```

Now I need  a way to quickly know the number of users we have on our system, there are hunders of thousands of users, so of course I'm not going to query them all and then count them on the client side, instead, I want to query them on the server, and let the server decide the amount of users we have.

By the way, I'm using MongoDB with node and Mongoose, so I believe the query should look similar to this even though I'm sure yet how it's gonna work:

```js
const numOfUsers = await User.find({}).count()
```

so this should return a number like 124321,

So the question is, where I should put this functionality in my API? is there a standard way to put the logic we might have in a URL? or where do we put these? is it like this?

```
# GET api/v1/users/count
```

Or should I place this somewhere in the request headers, since we don't have a body for the GET requests?

```js
# GET api/v1/users/
# request headers 
{
  ??? somewhere here
}
```

Comment: add data count value and other paginate related values on `meta` object.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `meta` object to your response which gonna have some properties like `total` which has the total count of `users` inside the database.

```json
{
  message: "success",
  meta: {
   total: 12314
  },
  data: [
   { id: 1, name: "A" },
   { id: 2, name: "B" },
   { id: 3, name: "C" },
  ]
}
```